# Is there a way to add a cancel button with an input field in Sweetalert, Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sweetalert

I'm trying to create an Swal alert that must contain an input field with a continue and cancel button in ReactJs. This is my code right now:

```
              swal({
                    icon: "warning",
                    text: 'Are you sure you want to continue? This operation is not reversible',
                    content: {
                        element: "input",
                        attributes: {
                          placeholder: title + " reason",
                        },
                      },
                }).then(comment => {
                    if (comment === null || comment === ''){
                        swal({icon: 'error', text: 'You need to type the cancellation reason'});
                        return false
                    }
                })
```

This code only creates an 'OK' button and I get the input from the user in the **comment** variable, but I need to add a 'Continue' button and a 'Cancel' button to leave the alert. I've tried adding the **button** parameter in the swal options and this creates the buttons but I'm not able to get the input from the user.

I also have tried to add raw html in the content and get the input with a handle method but so far I haven't been able to do this.

Maybe the solution for this is easy but I am not able to get it. Thank a lot for the help

Answer (score 0):

I found out a way to solve this in case anyone have to do something similar. I just created the input by doing document.createElement('input') and then I got the value depending on the user clicked on Continue or Cancel:

```
              const cancellation_reason = document.createElement('input');
              swal({
                    icon: "warning",
                    text: 'Are you sure you want to continue? This operation is not reversible',
                    content: {
                        element: cancellation_input,
                        attributes: {
                          placeholder: title + " reason",
                        },
                      },
                    buttons: {
                        continue: 'continue',
                        cancel: 'cancel'
                    }
                    
                }).then(option => {
                    switch (option){
                        case 'continue':
                            if (cancellation_input.value === null || cancellation_input.value === ''){
                                swal({icon: 'error', text: 'You need to type the cancellation reason'});
                                return false
                            }
                            prop(runID, null, path, cancellation_input.value).then(showMesagge);
                            break;
                        case 'cancel':
                            break;
                    }
                })
```